# '149 was not expected at this time'

Tags: batch-file

This is the part of the code that is oddly not working:

```
if %input%==1 (
  if %armorid% LSS 1 (
    if %money% GTR 149 (
      set /a money-=150
      set armorid=1
      set armor=Leather Armor
      goto shop2
    ) else (
      goto notenoughmoney
    )
  ) else (
    goto betteritem
  )
)
```

Of course, I have those variable set. (Otherwise I would've already found the solution.)

If you want the full code I'll post, but it's 1500 lines, and the rest works.

Comment: 1500 line batch program?!

Comment: Yeah, but of course not just this. It's a Batch RPG with random encounters and whatnot. But the shop's not working so yea

Comment: Someone halp lol, nobody tried to help yet.

Answer (score 1):

Rethinking my answer because I missed this bit: *"Of course, I have those variable set. (Otherwise I would've already found the solution.)"*.

What do you get if you change it to be:

```
if %input%==1 (
  if %armorid% LSS 1 (
    echo "HERE"
    echo %money%

    if %money% GTR 149 (
      set /a money-=150
...
```

does it print a value for `money` after "HERE"?

Comment: Wait, do you mean with the percent signs, or just money the variable itself?

Comment: Also, if you meant the variable without the percent signs, I already defined it; hence: "I already defined money".

Answer (score 1):

Although there are multiple possibilities and very little information, I could bet that you may solve this problem if you change this line:

```
    if %money% GTR 149 (
```

... by this one:

```
    if !money! GTR 149 (
```

... and insert this line at beginning of your program:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
```

For further details, look for "Delayed expansion" topic...